# Counting a specific value

Tags: java, count

I am trying to create a method that will count number of zeros in a statement/numbers (numOfZero), that a string as input and returns the number of occurrence of ‘0’ in the string.
And if there is no zero it should return zero. I have used String.length() and String.CharAt(int index). but getting some errors. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Could you show us what you have tried so far, in terms of code ?

Comment: How could we possibly help you without seeing the code or the errors? Please add both to your question (by editing it, don't post code in the comments)

Comment: *"but getting some errors."* What errors? We can't see your code so we can't offer any help. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] then post a proper [mre]

Comment: `return (int) s.codePoints.filter(cp -> cp == '0').count();`

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int countOccurance(int num){
    int count = 0;
    String aux = Integer.toString(num); //conversion Integer to string.
    for(int i= 0; i<aux.length(); i++){
        if(aux.charAt(i) == '0'){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This is the method. It counts how many zeros there are in your number. Try it!